# Is this the best way to convert a random value to a decimal?

Tags: php, math

I have a number I need to multiply by a random amount (1-4%)

In PHP terms, I was thinking..

```
$percent = (double) ".0".mt_rand(1,4);
```

Would that yield .01 - .04? in a number form, not a string?

If so great, but is there a safer/more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `$percent = mt_rand(1, 4)/100.0;`

Comment: I thought of casting before THAT? Good god I'm an idiot.. thank you so much. Do you know if my method would work (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: The way you have it, no. You would need to wrap the whole thing in `()` like so `(double)(".0".mt_rand(1,4));` Ex: http://viper-7.com/QWD6WA